# Cистема самовольно убивает Service и запускает его через неопределённое время

Tags: android, android-service

Есть Service:

```
public class I3 extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ...
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.mypackage.Restart"));
    }
    ...
}
```

Его запуск осуществляется при включении телефона с помощью BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class I2 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, I3.class));
    }
}
```

В манифесте всё объявлено корректно:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
...
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".I1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".I2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mypackage.Restart" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".I3"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
...
```

В методе `onStartCommand` Service запускает новый поток (`new MyThread().start();`, где `private class MyThread extends Thread {...}`).

Через некоторое время (примерно 20 часов) запущенный поток умирает по неизвестной причине. Затем, через некоторое время поступает команда запуска Service (вызывается метод `onStartCommand`). Как можно обосновать эти странные команды? Почему система самовольно убивает Service и запускает его вновь через неопределённый промежуток времени? Помогите решить проблему. Может можно вместо Service можно использовать какой-то более надёжный компонент, способный работать при выключенном экране телефона?

Answer (score 3):

> Почему система самовольно убивает Service

Это так работает ОС Android - система может убить любой сервис по своему собственному усмотрению. Например по причине нехватки памяти или еще другой причине.

> и запускает его вновь через неопределённый промежуток времени?

Потому что у вас он `START_STICKY`, фактически этот флаг - просьба системе после его "убийства" на автоматический повторный запуск.

Comment: Я понял проблему. Что делать? Я, на мой взгляд, сделал достаточно эффективный код Service по памяти. Может, есть какой флаг, строго запрещающий "убийство" Service? Play Market же "вечно" работает, система никогда не убивает его Service.

Comment: Нет такого флага. Единственное что могу посоветовать автоматический запуск сервиса при его закрытии. На enSO видел такое решение - погуглите